# Error in reading json file by using fromJSON in R

Tags: json, r

I have a problem to read json file by using `jsonlite::fromJSON`. It shows error message as below:

> Error in fromJSON(file = jsonfile.names[1]) : unexpected character 'N'.

It is a problem with `NaN` values in the json file. If I remove or change all the `NaN` to strings or numbers, `fromJSON` works just fine.

A sample of my data follows below:

```
{"name": NaN,
"unit_price": 130848,
"amount": 11,
"up_to_data_sales": 45725}
```

Is there any solution to solve this problem without manually changing the json file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955051/handling-nan-when-using-fromjson-in-r I found this post may be it will help

Comment: which package is your `fromJSON` from there are a few of them in CRAN

Answer (score 5):

That's not technically JSON. It's JavaScript.

We can use the `V8` package here:

```
library(V8)

jsraw <- '{"name": NaN, "unit_price": 130848, "amount": 11, "up_to_data_sales": 45725}'

ctx <- v8()
ctx$assign("dat", JS(jsraw))
ctx$get("dat")

## $name
## NULL
## 
## $unit_price
## [1] 130848
## 
## $amount
## [1] 11
## 
## $up_to_data_sales
## [1] 45725
```

You can obtain similar results with `RJSONIO::fromJSON(jsraw)` (hence me asking which JSON package you were using).

But, this is a toy example, so if we had more info from you we could probably come up with a more general solution.

Also, hand-editing data is generally a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using 'rjson' package.

Comment: I tried both 'rjson' and 'jsonlite' package. The 'fromJSON' function in both package is not compatible with the value of 'NaN' of the item. After i manually change the value of 'NaN' to 0 of these item, the function works fine. I don't know whether there is some decent solution on this. Thanks

Comment: So, why didn't you try one of the two solutions in this answer?

Comment: I tried the RJSONIO package and it works. The reading output of JSON is named numeric array. Thanks.